# Match open and close tag

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this string:

```
"<myTag att1="val1"><myTag></myTag></myTag><myTag></myTag>"
```

What I need is to match:

```
<myTag att1="val1"><myTag></myTag></myTag>
```

I tried with a regex but it gets:

```
<myTag att1="val1"><myTag></myTag>
```

How can I resolve?

Comment: what is your regex ? I think you should make the regex lazy like this : (.+?)

Comment: So, you have just found out that you cannot use *JS regex to parse nested HTML tags. **JS regex does not support recursion**. Next step: learn parsing HTML with DOM.

Comment: obligatory http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Answer (score 1):

Eliminate the default greedy nature and write something below:-

```
(.+?)
```

Please note, att1="val1" might not recognize in the string in few editors. Hence for that prefix a '\'. But the above regex should work

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
/(<myTag(\satt1="val1")*>)+(<\/myTag>)*/g
```